# Default margin when using Text QML type

Tags: qt, text, fonts, qml

Consider this simple code sample:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    color: "black"

    Text {
        text: "Hello World!"
        font.family: "Helvetica"
        font.pointSize: 24
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

[image]

Why is there a margin at the top? It seems that giving a custom font with a specific pixelSize gives a new size to the `Text` and breaks the alignement.

**EDIT**: well it seems that even without font there still is a margin.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour, can you share the whole QML file?

Comment: I've changed the whole post for clarity.

Comment: It seems to be a "windows thing" - android, linux and macos appear to produce consistent output.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution would be to set the attribute `y` of the `Text` like this:

```
Text {
    text: "Hello World!"
    font.family: "Helvetica"
    font.pixelSize: 42
    color: "red"
    y: -contentHeight + font.pixelSize
}
```

Bear in mind that if you set the property `font.overline: true` then it will be out of the `Rectangle`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove this extra space with the use of FontMetrics but this solution seems way too complicated for this simple problem. Waiting for a better fix.

```
Window {
    visible: true
    color: "black"

FontMetrics {
    id: fontmetrics24
    font.pixelSize: 24
    font.family: "Helvetica"
}

    Text {
        text: "Hello World!"
        font.family: fontmetrics24.font.family
        font.pointSize: fontmetrics24.font.pixelSize
        color: "red"
        y: - fontmetrics24.height * 0.21
    }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't noticed that before... it's weird. But if you set the property `font.overline: true` you can see that it matches exactly the top of your rectangle

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552072/text-in-qml-rendered-different-accross-platforms). On macOS (Sierra), the window looks like this:

[image]

As [ddriver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991484/ddriver) pointed out, this is probably a bug and is already reported [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56052).